# Not able to "click()" a radio element with Selenium

Tags: selenium

Below is the html.

```
<input type="radio" onclick="getOrgList('1000149');" value="1000149" name="wlw-radio_button_group_key:{pageFlow.viewBy}">
```

I am using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='wlw-radio_button_group_key:{pageFlow.viewBy}' and @value='1000149']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='1000149']")).click();
```

but nothing happened. How can I fix this?

Comment: Share the HTML for that element

Comment: Provide details about your selenium server version and browser which you are using.

Comment: What driver? What browser? What version of that browser? What version of Selenium? What OS? Is the element available *straight away*? Does the page take time to load?

Comment: please see the given link, it might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14734369/1376581

Answer (score 0):

The possible case which seems for non- functioning of locator may be if this radio button is second or third in its group.As Radio buttons belonging to a Group have same name 
If this be the case Then u can use "following" like
//input[contains(@name,'wlw-radio_button_group_key:{pageFlow.viewBy}')]/following::input[contains(@name,'wlw-radio_button_group_key:{pageFlow.viewBy}')]

U can follow it more if there are more buttons in the group.